# Getting number of support vectors of a RBF SVC in a sklearn pipeline

Tags: python, svm, scikit-learn-pipeline

Is it possible to get the number of support vectors and (or) their values for an RBF SVC when it is fit using a sklearn Pipeline object?
My pipeline looks like this

```
dim_reduction = TruncatedSVD( n_components = dim_reduction_n_comp, random_state = 611 )   
classifier_obj = sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline([
        ('scaler', sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
        ( 'dim_reduction', dim_reduction ),
        ( 'svc', sklearn.svm.SVC(C= svc_c, gamma = svc_gamma, probability = True ) )
    ])
```

I want to calculate the footprint of the SVC by getting the support vectors and their coefficients and use it as a parameter to optuna optimization study.

Comment: Have you check [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) for the attributes of the SVC? A fitted SVC object has attributes for `support_vectors_` and `coef_` that you can access, have you tried either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Number of support vectors** for each class can be retrieved from the property `n_support_` of the `SVC` object, using:

`classifier_obj[2].n_support_`

The result will be an `ndarray` of shape (n_classes,) with integers which represent the number of vectors for each class, in the corresponding order as in the property `classes_`, which contains the classes labels:

`classifier_obj[2].classes_`

Comment: Thank you. That helps. I am trying to figure out the size of the ```classifier_obj```. I can use the brute method of using something like ```len(pickle.dumps(classifier_obj))```. However, I am trying to use something more meaningful and explainable, like adding the size of the support vectors and dim_reduction matrices, (```sum( n_support) * n_features +( n_features * n_componets) + ...```.

Comment: Glad to know it helped. If you please vote up on my answer, that would be appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not. Stackoverflow told me that I am too new for upvoting and need to earn more reputation before I can do it...

Comment: No rush, come back later once you have the possibility to upvote ;)